# SELECT QUERY: How can I select a specific data on my table to display

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query below. hope someone can help me with it, I need to display ONLY all "Checking" and "Validated" under **[Tbl_Aspac].[request_mode]**

```
SELECT [Tbl_Aspac].[request_number],
       [Tbl_Aspac].[platform],
       [Tbl_Aspac].[request_type],
       [Tbl_Aspac].[environment],
       [Tbl_Aspac].[id_fid],
       [Tbl_Aspac].[requestor],
       [Tbl_Aspac].[request_mode],/*←——*/
       [Tbl_Aspac].[isa_resolver],
       [Tbl_Aspac].[logged_date],
       [Tbl_Aspac].[request_medium],
       [Tbl_Aspac].[closed_date],
       [Tbl_Aspac].[host_name]
FROM Tbl_Aspac
ORDER BY [request_number];
```

As of now there's "Checking" , "Validated" and "Completed" entries, I don't want to display the "Completed" ones only the validate and Checking

I used it for my Microsoft Access project. Thanks

the table looks like this

[image]

Comment: "Checking" , "Validated" and "Completed" entries will present in which column

Comment: [request_mode] @Chanukya

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Tbl_Aspac].[request_number], [Tbl_Aspac].[platform], [Tbl_Aspac].[request_type], [Tbl_Aspac].[environment], [Tbl_Aspac].[id_fid], [Tbl_Aspac].[requestor], [Tbl_Aspac].[request_mode], [Tbl_Aspac].[isa_resolver], [Tbl_Aspac].[logged_date], [Tbl_Aspac].[request_medium], [Tbl_Aspac].[closed_date], [Tbl_Aspac].[host_name] FROM Tbl_Aspac WHERE [Tbl_Aspac].[request_mode] in ('Checking','Validated') ORDER BY [request_number];
```

Check this.. Hope this helps